# NodeJS CPU utilization in cluster mode

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing

I am creating an application which is running on NodeJSv10.8.0 and Dynamoose. I am experiencing unusual CPU utilization when it is running in Cluster mode with just 500 concurrent virtual users on a simple signup API. All my cores are running at 100%. I am running the application in cluster mode with 4 instances. Can someone help me in understanding if this behavior is normal? What kinda CPU utilization should I see when I am running in cluster mode even and loading an API with 500vU on a simple API. Sorry if am not making myself clear but I need to understand how a CPU behaves in a cluster mode on production as this is my first time preparing for a high load application. Let me know if something is not clear. I have attached some graphs of my ec2 instance for reference. I am running a c5.XL machine.

[CPU utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u82yu.png)

Comment: Are you using node.js clustering right? if so please show the code. This is not expected behaviour except you are performing heavy computation work in signup. As you are using `c5.XL` this should easily handle the 500 request.

Comment: I am using pm2 to handle clustering.

Comment: @Aabid I should think so.

Comment: Can you implement clustering in code and observe the behaviour. It would help to track down the problem

Comment: I have done that as well. It does not alter the utilization much. @Aabid

Comment: Can you show me the `signup` code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Nikhil2508/d9a87d59d07f0defbcb97b359cc5ea41  Here you go @Aabid

Comment: your code doesn't have any issue. I think when you will increase the load by 4X your server will not goes down, because in graph it is showing 100% utilisation of single core, remaining cores are free. Means your cpu usage can go upto 400% because you have 4 cores. Use `top` command and monitor cpu usage. I hope it make sense.

Comment: Hey @Aabid, I did use top and all cores do get utilized to full potential. Infact even this much usage is not normal. Any chance you can replicate it on your end?